# How do I use IceWM's 'icesh' command to set the task-bar layer to 'Normal'?

Tags: linux, icewm

The current taskbar layer is stuck on "onTop" and I would like to change it to "Normal" so it will be hidden when not focused.

A similar issue to mine can be found [here](https://github.com/jarcode-foss/glava/issues/3) but I'm unfamiliar with Linux and have no direct access to the configuration files, therefore I'm trying to solve it through the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set an Icewm property of a window, you need its [class and/or instance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494169/388654), which you can find with [Icesh](https://github.com/ice-wm/man/blob/master/icesh.md):

```
icesh list
```

Then click the desired window. For an Xterm, you will find **xterm.XTerm** as the **class.instance** value* in the next-to-last field.

Then one would use that value in [`~/.icewm/winoptions`](https://github.com/ice-wm/man/blob/master/icewm-winoptions.md) to set a property; say, to display no title bar for Xterms:

```
xterm.XTerm.dTitleBar: 0
```

and restart Icewm.

---

Now, the task bar is a special window for which Icewm does not seem to honor a `winoptions` setting anymore (although older versions did, see [the revision history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/564629/2)). Still, there are several options for it in the [`preferences`](https://github.com/ice-wm/man/blob/master/icewm-preferences.md#task-bar) file, for example to set its layer to *Below*. If you absolutely want it to set it to *Normal*,

```
icesh setLayer Normal
```

or if you don't want to point-and-click,

```
icesh -w "$(xdotool search --class '^icewm$' search --name '^TaskBar$')" setLayer Normal
```

<sup>*`xprop | grep CLASS` can also be used to retrieve that information.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In preferences set:

`TaskBarKeepBelow=1`

or use:

`icesh -T setLayer Normal`