# How to open new files in a same Vim instance from my file manager or from command-line?

Tags: command-line, terminal, x11, vim, file-manager

I don't usually navigate my filesystem from Vim,
but instead use a file manager and sometimes
even the good, old interactive shell (command line).

Issuing `vim file` from the command line or from a terminal based file
manager (MC, Vifm, Ranger, ...) totally defeats their purpose of navigation,
since Vim takes over the terminal, blocking the shell or file manager.
Of course, even this is impossible for GUI file managers since they don't
run in a terminal.

A general solution is to use `xterm -e vim file &`
to open each desired file in its own terminal, but
after some time I end up with various
open terminals, each with a file, and cycling through them with
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> becomes cumbersome.

Is there a way to open
every new file from my navigation utility (whatever it is) in a new buffer/tab of
a **same** existing Vim instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First make sure `vim --version | grep clientserver` returns
`+clientserver`.  If it returns `-` instead of `+`, an easy way to enable
that capability is to install Gvim, even though we won't use it.
In Debian and Ubuntu, `sudo apt install vim-athena`
installs it. An alternative for experienced users who definetly want to skip
Gvim is to [build Vim from sources with flags `--with-x=yes --disable-gui`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/30787).

Now that you have `+clientserver`, create the file `vimserver` with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
serv=${S:-xtvim}
if vim --serverlist | grep -qxiF "$serv"; then
    vim --servername "$serv" --remote-tab "$@"
else
    xterm -e vim -p --servername "$serv" "$@" &
fi
```

Don't forget to put `vimserver` in a directory in your [`$PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998452/where-should-i-put-my-bash-scripts)
and to make it executable with `chmod +x vimserver`.
If you use other terminal, find in its manpage what is
the appropriate flag to execute the command in a new terminal window<sup>1</sup>.

Test it on some files (multiple files can be passed in the arguments):

```
vimserver file1 file2
vimserver file3 file4 file5
S=xyz vimserver file6
```

Each file opens in a new tab of a same Vim instance named "XTVIM",
except for `file6`, which goes to a different instance, "XYZ".
If you want new files to be in a new buffer,
just change `--remote-tab` to `--remote` and remove the `-p` flag.

#### Explaining `vimserver`

The server name, assigned to the `serv` variable, defaults to "xtvim", but as seen
above a different one can be specified with the environment variable `S`.

Grep looks for the exact value of `serv` in the server list (but case-insensitively
since Vim forces its server names to uppercase).
If it is found, that server loads the file, otherwise, a new terminal is launched
and the server with it.

#### Requesting focus

The terminal is not focused when a file is opened in
an already existing server; Setting an [*instance
name*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494169/wm-class-vs-wm-instance/494170) for the window and adding a Xdotool line solves that:

```
#!/bin/sh
serv=${S:-xtvim}
if vim --serverlist | grep -qxiF "$serv"; then
    xdotool search --classname "^$serv$" windowactivate
    vim --servername "$serv" --remote-tab "$@"
else
    xterm -name "$serv" -e vim -p --servername "$serv" "$@" &
fi
```

Because of the `-name` option, Xdotool can locate the Vim window and request
focus to it. Some terminals lack that option but have `--role`, which Xdotool
can also use for `search` since version 3.20210804.2.

#### File managers

**Vifm**

Edit [`~/.config/vifm/vifmrc`](https://wiki.vifm.info/index.php/Quickstart_Tutorial#Opening_files):

```
filextype <text/*> vimserver %f
```

Multiple files can be opened at the same via visual mode or tagging.

**Midnight Commander**

Edit the extension file `~/.config/mc/mc.ext`:

```
type/text
 Open=vimserver %s
```

Tagging multiple files is also possible in MC.

**GUI file-managers**

For many of them, the procedure is
right clicking a text file, `Open with... > Custom command line / Use a custom command`.
In the command text field, enter `vimserver` and, if any, mark a checkbox or press the button that sets it as default.

#### Gvim

If you are OK with Gvim<sup>2</sup>, do not bother with `vimserver`. Just use
`gvim --remote-tab-silent`.

<sup>1: Gnome-terminal, Xfce4-terminal and Terminator use the `-x` flag, not `-e`.</sup>
<sup>2: Goldilocks comments about the Gvim usage in
[What are practical uses of the client-server mode?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7968).</sup>

Comment: `gvim --remote <filename>` opens a file in a buffer in an existing gvim instance.

Comment: @Quasimodo is there anyway to open in same GVim instance in same virtual desktop? Or it's not possible? Thanks

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto You can easily find the window ID of the Gvim window in a specific desktop with `wmctrl`. If Gvim offers a way to retrieve the window ID (I don't know whether it does), then you can close the circuit.